# How to share common key board & mouse across laptops?

Tags: kvm

I have two work laptops. One came with a docking  station & external monitor.

I’m using two different keyboard & mouse.

I want to use same keyboard & mouse & switch across one laptop to another.

I am not supposed to install any third party softwares.

My understanding about kvm switch is to connect multiple computers & share common monitor, keyboard , mouse.

In this scenario, 2 laptops has its own screens.

Answer (score 1):

A KVM switch would be what you need. They are meant to control two or more computers from a single keyboard, mouse, and monitor. The keyboard and mouse are on one side of it. The monitor is on the other. That being said, you should be able to use a KVM switch without connecting anything to the monitor ports. This would allow each computer to operate with its own screen but same keyboard and mouse.

Just to be clear, with a KVM switch, you can only control one computer at a time. You will press a sequence of keys to switch computers. If you want to control them both at the same time with the same keystrokes, look into a USB splitter instead.

Comment: not really. Because. I don't want to switch back and forth from one laptop to another. I work on two laptops parallel .. without switching , only by moving the mouse ( pointing ) to the screen where i work.

Comment: If you are wanting to, in essence, use both computers as one, you would be better off sharing information. Connect one laptop to the other through USB cable, crossover cable, or local intranet. This would treat one as a media device and the other as the computer.

As far as I know, there is no way to make both be a computer with their own screens while sharing a mouse and keyboard that you can move between screens. A USB splitter would allow the same mouse and keyboard on both screens doing the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

A software KVM might be useful:

- [Mouse Without Borders](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=35460)
- [Input Director](https://www.inputdirector.com/)
- [Share Mouse](http://www.keyboard-and-mouse-sharing.com/)

You share one mouse & keyboard but not screens and in most cases you can move from machine to machine without even a keypress (the latter two options definitely support this).

Comment: Thank you !! I realized that, this can be possible only with a third party software and not just with external peripherals